# apt-get warnings about multiverse?

Tags: apt, server

Every time I use apt-get update I get the following warnings

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse//binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse//i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse//cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse/' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Not sure is this is something I should worry about or not? I have googled for these warnings but can't find anyone who has the same warning, only the same kind of warning.

Whats in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe restricted m$
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe restricted mu$
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
```

Second command:
    `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep multiverse` :

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe restricted multiverse/
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full text of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: what the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep multiverse`? please including that output into your question!

Comment: @OrganicMarble Done

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the / after multiverse in the bionic-updates line.

You can see the erroneous double slash in your error message.

`multiverse**//**binary-amd64/Packages`

then try `sudo apt update` again.